# No hat for silver badge

Tags: bug, winter-bash-2014

I've earned a silver badge and my hat "werewolf hunter" is not enabled.

Here is the screen

[image]

And my hat is not wearable

[image]

Is it a bug or a pebkac ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Those silver badges are earned on Meta Stack Overflow. Hats cannot be earned on child metas.

Comment: Damn it ! I will accept your answer in 10 minutes :)